# How can I reuse MediaCodec for decode

Tags: video, android-mediacodec, hevc

In my App, I use MediaCodec to play video. its video format is h265.

I want to reuse codec, when a video play completed, these codec's csd-0 data are different.

I don't know how to use BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG this flag to impl.

My code is:

```kotlin
object Sample {
    fun createCodec(type: VideoType, format: MediaFormat, surface: Surface): MediaCodec {
        val codec = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(type)
        codec.configure(
            format,
            surface,
            null,
            0
        )
        codec.start()
       return codec
    }
    

    fun flush(codec: MediaCodec) {
        codec.flush()
    }

    
    fun reuseCodec(codec: MediaCodec, surface: Surface, format: MediaFormat) {
        
        codec.flush()
        codec.setOutputSurface(surface)

        val csd0Buffer = format.getByteBuffer("csd-0")

        while (true) {
            val index = codec.dequeueInputBuffer(0)
            if (index < 0) {
                continue
            }

            val inputBuffer = codec.getInputBuffer(index)
            inputBuffer.put(csd0Buffer)
            codec.queueInputBuffer(
                    index,
                    0,
                    csd0Buffer.size,
                    0,
                    MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG
            )

            break
        }
        
    }

}
```

I have two url, these csd-0 data is different `width`, `height` is the same.

Steps:

1. play url1 -> createCodec
2. url1 play complete -> flush
3. play url2 -> reuseCodec
4. dequeueOutputBufferIndex always -1

How can I solve it?

Comment: I see that you set zero timeout here:
val index = codec.dequeueInputBuffer(0)
have you tried to set non zero values e.g. 100000? also keep in mind that this value is microseconds and not milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks for your replay!
I think this is not the cause of the problem, I tried to wait for more than a minute, but it is still -1.

Maybe I used a decoder with configured state. These video's csd-0 csd-1 data is different. I tried queueInputBuffer with these csd-0 csd-1 data, but It's useless